# Chrome extension not loading after using SplitChunksPlugin in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to reduce bundle weight of a Chrome extension / Firefox add-on built with React 17.0.2 + Webpack 5.7 + Typescript 4.3.5. This is how my **webpack.common.js** file looks like:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const manifestJson = require('./assets/manifest.json');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserExtensionWebpackPlugin = require('./tools/browser_extension_webpack_plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const distDir = (function () {
  switch (process.env.BROWSER) {
    case 'chrome':
      return 'dist_crx';
    case 'firefox':
      return 'dist_ff';
    default:
      throw new Error('BROWSER not supported');
  }
})();

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/global/popup.js',
    background: './src/global/bg/index.js',
    local_backup_page: './src/global/page-local-backup/local_backup.tsx',
    page_options: './src/global/page-options/options.js',
    payment_cs: './src/global/cs/cs_payment.js',
    payment_inject: './src/global/inject/inject_payment.js',
    updatecard_cs: './src/global/cs/cs_updatecard.js',
    updatecard_inject: './src/global/inject/inject_updatecard.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, distDir),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    alias: {
      ga: path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        process.env.BROWSER === 'firefox'
          ? './src/utils/lib/GoogleAnalytics/ga_mock.js'
          : './src/utils/lib/GoogleAnalytics/ga.js',
      ),
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
    },
    fallback: {
      http: false,
      https: false,
      assert: false,
      tls: false,
      fs: false,
      net: false,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    // new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    //   filename: 'tailwind.css',
    // }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'assets/html/main.html' }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'html', 'main.html'),
      filename: 'main.html',
      chunks: ['main'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'html', 'background.html'),
      filename: 'background.html',
      chunks: ['background'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'html', 'options.html'),
      filename: 'options.html',
      chunks: ['page_options'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'html', 'local_backup.html'),
      filename: 'local_backup.html',
      chunks: ['local_backup_page'],
    }),
    new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: 'assets',
          to: path.resolve(__dirname, distDir),
          // transform: function (content, filepath) {
          //   if (process.env.BROWSER !== 'firefox') return content;
          //   if (filepath.indexOf('manifest.json') === -1) return content;
          //   return content;
          //   // return ('' + content).replace(/\s*"content_security_policy".*?\n/g, '\n');
          // },
        },
      ],
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __BROWSER__: JSON.stringify(process.env.BROWSER),
      __VERSION__: JSON.stringify(manifestJson.version),
    }),
    new BrowserExtensionWebpackPlugin({
      createManifestJson: ({}) => {
        if (process.env.BROWSER === 'firefox') {
          delete manifestJson.content_security_policy;
          delete manifestJson.key;
          delete manifestJson.oauth2;
          delete manifestJson.options_page;
          delete manifestJson.background.persistent;
          manifestJson.permissions = manifestJson.permissions.filter(
            (str) => str !== 'identity.email',
          );
        } else {
          delete manifestJson.applications;
        }

        return manifestJson;
      },
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      generateStatsFile: true,
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        antd: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]antd[\\/]/,
          name: 'antd',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
        moment: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]moment[\\/]/,
          name: 'moment',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Chunks are already been created for **moment** and **antd**, the extension is not loading though

[blank extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Eey.png)

After checking on the page elements, **root** element in DOM looks empty:

[html elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT7Y3.png)

I've been struggling a while with this and I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Check the devtools console (of the popup) and the contents of `<head>`.

Comment: Dependencies are not been injected in the head tag of html file, I'm not sure why though